# Ionic 3 performance issue with Firestore and AngularFire

Tags: firebase, ionic3, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm experiencing performance issue with very slow loading when my collection goes over 20 documents.

Here is my app structure

I got a `FeedComponent` which collect `Post` subscribing to a Firestore collection

```
getAllPost(type: string){
    return this.afs.collection(`posts`, ref =>
      ref.orderBy("created", "desc")
        .where("type", "==", type))
      .snapshotChanges(["added"]).map(actions => {

        return actions.map(a => {
          //console.log(a)
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      });
  }
```

then for each `Post`from Firestore create a `PostComponent`

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
            <post *ngIf="post" [userId]="userId" [postId]="post.id" [author]="post.user" [created]="post.created" [postContent]="post.post" [postPicture]="post.picturePath" [firstName]="post.first_name" [lastName]="post.last_name"></post>
</div>
```

Then this `PostComponent` has is own set of Observable to retrieve specific information base on the payload, so it generates additional call to Firestore

After my post number goes over 20, the app becomes super sloppy.
I guess I got too many Observable going on.

What would be a better strategy?